# Copy and paste from photoshop to illustrator and maintain transparency?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

Hi is it possible to copy something in photoshop and paste it into illustrator and maintain the transparency instead of having a white background?

Comment: Drag and drop usually works better but copy/paste should work. Copy/paste is somewhat dependent upon you OS because the clipboard is used.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Library panel (Available in CC). The library panel deals with transferring artwork between Adobe programs much better than copy/paste drag/drop.

In Photoshop drag your artwork to the Library panel. (Window -> Libraries)

In Illustrator drag the artwork from your libraries panel to your artboard. (Window -> Libraries)

Comment: It worked!! Thanks so much. Did not know about libraries panel.